# Base class variables were `not declared in its scope`

Tags: c++, inheritance

I am trying to go through C++ inheritance and I have a problem with my code. I have the base class Caine and CaineCuPete derived from it. I get an error when I declare the derived class constructor.

```
CaineCuPete(int nPete) : Caine(cNume,cHeight,cWeight,cAge,cColor);
```

Error:

> cNume was not declared in its scope. cHeight was not declared in its
>   scope. ...

Comment: You need to take these as input parameters in your derived class constructor.

Comment: Please provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), since people can only wildly guess what `cNume` etc. might be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to take these as input parameters in your derived class constructor.

```
CaineCuPete(int nPete, string cNume, double cHeight, 
    double cWeight, double cAge, int cColor ) : Caine(cNume,cHeight,cWeight,cAge,cColor),
Pete ( nPete )
{
}
```

This link explains:
http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/114-constructors-and-initialization-of-derived-classes/

Comment: This also prints an error, saying it expects `{` at the end of input. The constructor is declared in the .cpp file, does it have to be implemented inline?

Comment: Yes, I guess so because you are passing the parameters to base class constructor directly.

Comment: I'm very confused right now. Do you have a link for some further reading into this?

Comment: @johnjhye link added.

Answer (score 1):

You should define your variables `cNume,cHeight,cWeight,cAge,cColor` before the first use. A common problem is that they are defined after the point of use, not before.

Comment: But those are not constants, they will be read from user input..

Comment: They still need to be defined somewhere. Note that you can't use member variables of `CaineCuPete` when calling its base constructor.

Comment: @johnjhye Then you need to pass them as arguments to the `CaineCuPete` - constructor, like Abhishek Bansal said